# Rails Saving Models in Wrong Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

i've been searching around for some time now and can't seem to figure out what is causing this, I had a model working saving a volunteer and his home and work addresses. I changed something (cant seem to figure out what for the life of me) and now the address isnt being set.

This is my main model:

```
class HumanVolunteer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :primaryPhone, :class_name => "PhoneNumber", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "phone_id"
  has_one :primaryEmail, :class_name => "Email", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "email_id"
  has_one :work_adr, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "workaddressid"
  has_one :home_adr, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "homeaddressid"

  attr_accessible :firstName, :lastName, :homeaddressid, :notes, :status, :workaddressid, :home_adr, :work_adr, 
              :primaryPhone, :primaryEmail, :home_adr_attributes, :work_adr_attributes, :primaryPhone_attributes, 
              :primaryEmail_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :home_adr 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_adr 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primaryPhone
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primaryEmail
end
```

and the address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :line1, :line2, :notes, :state, :zipcode
  belongs_to :human_volunteer
end
```

Heres a snippet from the human_volunteers_controller

```
# GET /human_volunteers/new
  # GET /human_volunteers/new.json
  def new
    @human_volunteer = HumanVolunteer.new
    @human_volunteer.build_home_adr
    @human_volunteer.build_work_adr
    @human_volunteer.build_primaryPhone
    @human_volunteer.build_primaryEmail

    # Set the Breadcrumbs for this page
    @breadcrumbs = { "Dashboard" => "/", "Human Volunteers" => "/human_volunteers"}
    @current_page = "New Volunteer"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @human_volunteer }
    end
  end

  # GET /human_volunteers/1/edit
  def edit
    @human_volunteer = HumanVolunteer.find(params[:id])
    if(@human_volunteer.home_adr.nil?)
      @human_volunteer.build_home_adr
    end

    if(@human_volunteer.work_adr.nil?)  
      @human_volunteer.build_work_adr
    end

    if(@human_volunteer.primaryPhone.nil?)
      @human_volunteer.build_primaryPhone
    end

    if(@human_volunteer.primaryEmail.nil?)
      @human_volunteer.build_primaryEmail
    end

    @breadcrumbs = { "Dashboard" => "/", "Human Volunteers" => "/human_volunteers"}
    @current_page = "Edit Volunteer: <em>" + @human_volunteer.firstName + " " + @human_volunteer.lastName + "</em>";
  end

  # POST /human_volunteers
  # POST /human_volunteers.json
  def create
    # create the volunteer
    @human_volunteer = HumanVolunteer.new(params[:human_volunteer])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @human_volunteer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @human_volunteer, :notice => @human_volunteer.firstName + ' ' + @human_volunteer.lastName + ' was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @human_volunteer, :status => :created, :location => @human_volunteer }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @human_volunteer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /human_volunteers/1
  # PUT /human_volunteers/1.json
  def update
    @human_volunteer = HumanVolunteer.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @human_volunteer.update_attributes(params[:human_volunteer])
        format.html { redirect_to @human_volunteer, :notice => @human_volunteer.firstName + ' ' + @human_volunteer.lastName + ' was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @human_volunteer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I can see what i think the problem is by looking at the logs, the human volunteer get saved first, using nulls for the address keys, then the addresses are saved ( also same problem with phone number and email models, they are set up identically to the addresses ) then the addresses are saved, and then the human volunteer is never updated again with the new values:

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"dD+ut6noFPw8mJHq4rUJpuNBD1o+q0Hi8a+qOeetzMc=", "utf8"=>"✓", "human_volunteer"=>{"lastName"=>"Koch", "work_adr_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"", "line2"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "state"=>"", "city"=>""}, "primaryEmail_attributes"=>{"email"=>""}, "primaryPhone_attributes"=>{"number"=>""}, "notes"=>"", "home_adr_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"123 Who Knows land", "line2"=>"", "zipcode"=>"11741", "state"=>"TS", "city"=>"testville"}, "firstName"=>"Ken", "status"=>"Investigative Candidate"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "human_volunteers" ("created_at", "email_id", "firstName", "homeaddressid", "lastName", "notes", "phone_id", "status", "updated_at", "workaddressid") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["email_id", nil], ["firstName", "Ken"], ["homeaddressid", nil], ["lastName", "Koch"], ["notes", ""], ["phone_id", nil], ["status", "Investigative Candidate"], ["updated_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["workaddressid", nil]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "phone_numbers" ("created_at", "notes", "number", "phone_id", "phone_type", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["notes", nil], ["number", ""], ["phone_id", nil], ["phone_type", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "emails" ("created_at", "email", "notes", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["email", ""], ["notes", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("city", "created_at", "line1", "line2", "notes", "state", "updated_at", "zipcode") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["city", ""], ["created_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["line1", ""], ["line2", ""], ["notes", nil], ["state", ""], ["updated_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["zipcode", nil]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("city", "created_at", "line1", "line2", "notes", "state", "updated_at", "zipcode") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["city", "testville"], ["created_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["line1", "123 Who Knows land"], ["line2", ""], ["notes", nil], ["state", "TS"], ["updated_at", Tue, 07 Aug 2012 16:47:16 UTC +00:00], ["zipcode", 11741]]
  (17.8ms)  COMMIT
```

EDIT: If this is any help here is an example of the old entry in the log:

```
Started POST "/human_volunteers" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Jul 28 09:08:59 -0400 2012
Processing by HumanVolunteersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"human_volunteer"=>{"firstName"=>"Ken", "work_adr"=>{"city"=>"", "state"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "line1"=>"", "line2"=>""}, "status"=>"Trainee", "home_adr"=>{"city"=>"fdsa", "state"=>"Nasdf", "zipcode"=>"11729", "line1"=>"asdf fdsafd", "line2"=>""}, "primaryEmail"=>"ken.koch@essencedesigns.net", "primaryPhone"=>"6316813806", "lastName"=>"Koch", "notes"=>"\r\nHes a good guy"}, "authenticity_token"=>"bgbecE+nMxNrPtleNOLfO/MqRib0cXmDMqL5JaPyC10=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "emails" ("created_at", "email", "notes", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["email", "ken.koch@essencedesigns.net"], ["notes", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (19.1ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "phone_numbers" ("created_at", "notes", "number", "phone_id", "phone_type", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["created_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["notes", nil], ["number", "6316813806"], ["phone_id", nil], ["phone_type", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (56.9ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (2.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("city", "created_at", "line1", "line2", "notes", "state", "updated_at", "zipcode") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["city", ""], ["created_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["line1", ""], ["line2", ""], ["notes", nil], ["state", ""], ["updated_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["zipcode", nil]]
  [1m[36m (9.4ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "addresses" ("city", "created_at", "line1", "line2", "notes", "state", "updated_at", "zipcode") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["city", "Deer Park"], ["created_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["line1", "294 West 15th St"], ["line2", ""], ["notes", nil], ["state", "NY"], ["updated_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["zipcode", 11729]]
  [1m[35m (7.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.1ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "human_volunteers" ("created_at", "email_id", "firstName", "homeaddressid", "lastName", "notes", "phone_id", "status", "updated_at", "workaddressid") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["email_id", 5], ["firstName", "Ken"], ["homeaddressid", 14], ["lastName", "Koch"], ["notes", "\r\nHes a good guy"], ["phone_id", 11], ["status", "Trainee"], ["updated_at", Sat, 28 Jul 2012 13:08:59 UTC +00:00], ["workaddressid", 13]]
  [1m[36m (6.1ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/human_volunteers/1
Completed 302 Found in 178ms (ActiveRecord: 112.1ms)
```

I was able to look back into the log and find one that worked, and the human_volunteer was the last thing inserted. It inserted addresses, emails, phones first, then used those id's when inserting the volunteer.

EDIT: I can also report that I am not getting any errors, everything goes through, just the data isnt connected.

Any ideas what could cause the change in the order? I can't see that  i changed anything that affected this.

UPDATE: I tried changing the has_one lines and was able to at least produce an error (for better or worse), when i cahnged the lines to:

```
  has_one :workaddress, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "workaddress"
  has_one :homeaddress, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => "homeaddress"
```

It tries to use the addressid 1 everytime and i get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "addresses_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Also if i take out the primary_key field, it seems to work, but it tries to set them both to the same address and i get the same error except with the next id (22, 23, 24 etc each time i try it)

Maybe that sheds some light on the problem? I'm going to keep prodding around.

Thank you very much, 
- Ken

Comment: Can't you look in your commit history to see what you modified?

Comment: I'm not sure how rails mangles names with NameCasing, but shouldn't *belongs_to :human_volunteer* be *belongs_to :humanvolunteer*?

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies, I tried using :humanvolunteer instead but no luck. And i havent started using version control yet (just in the early phases of working things out) so i dont have any way to roll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with what seems to be a viable solution.

Since once the id was initially set, everything seemed to work, i just manually linked it up in the controller under the create action:

```
@human_volunteer.homeaddress.save
@human_volunteer.homeaddressid = @human_volunteer.homeaddress.id
@human_volunteer.workaddress.save
@human_volunteer.workaddressid = @human_volunteer.workaddress.id
```

Now the address gets set when the volunteer is created and everything else should carry out nicely.

The only additional consideration i can see would be making sure that when i add validators to the address that the addresses can actually validate before allowing the creation of the entire thing.

Thanks everyone,

-Ken